# Solution of first order differential equation with integral type initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Suppose we want to solve the ODE

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = f(t)x(t)$$ with initial condition
$$x(0) = c_{1}+c_{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} g(t)x(t)dt $$
where $f$ and $g$ are continuous function.
Then is it possible to find the explicit solution of this differential equation?

I derived the solution but I got it in the implicit form i.e. solution itself depends on $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As

$$
x(t) = e^{\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau}c_0
$$

after substitution we have

$$
x(0) = c_{1}+c_{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} g(t)e^{\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau}c_0dt 
$$

and finally solving for $c_0$

$$
x(0) = c_{1}+c_{2}\phi(c_0) 
$$